# How to improve regex to verify/test and match a string like "1w 10d 5h 10s 5m"?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that consists of multiple small parts containing amounts of time:

```
1w 10d 5h 10m 4s
```

This reads like:
*1 week, 10 days, 5 hours, 10 minutes and 4 seconds*.

There a a few things that are allowed, like:

- using no whitesapces like `5d10h` between segments
- using multipe whiteshpaces like `5d    10h` between segments
- using `,` instead of `.` to separate decimals
- having a unit used multiple times, like `1d 5h 5d`

These things are not allowed:

- using other characters then `0-9 w d h m s , \. \s`, like `5x`
- starting a sequence with a letter, like `w10h` (`1w10h` is still allowed)

---

I came up with this regex:

```
const regex = /(\d+([\.|,]\d+)?[w|d|h|m|s])/gi;
```

It works fine, as it captures all valid segments in an array using `.match()`. Unfortunately `.test()` is always returning true if at least one match is found.

*How can I improve the regex so that `.test()` will fail for invalid strings, like in the code snippet below?*

```js
const regex = /(\d+([\.|,]\d+)?[w|d|h|m|s])/gi;
const value = '1w 5d 4.6h 5.2m    7.42s 10,10s 6h5m 10H 5,0H 5x w10h  ';

const isMatching = regex.test(value);
const matches = value.match(regex);

console.log(isMatching);
console.log(matches);
```

Comment: The primary issue with this usage of [RegExp.test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) usage is the regular expression is _not anchored_. Thus, if it matches _anywhere_ in the string..

Comment: Anyway, if this were my problem, I might split on spaces and then match each "part" individually.

Comment: @user2864740 Thanks for your help. I now understand, why everything was matching. I was thinking that it's easier as a validator of an input to test it against a single regex rather then split it up and test everything in a loop. But you're right. The naive approach is often a very good one. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could repeat the match preceded by 0+ whitespace chars without matching a newline. Add anchors to assert the start and the end of the string.

You can omit the `|` in the character class as it would match the pipe literally instead of meaning OR.

```
^\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?[wdhms](?:[^\S\r\n]*\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?[wdhms])*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/atNYTx/1)

```js
const pattern = /^\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?[wdhms](?:[^\S\r\n]*\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?[wdhms])*$/;
[
  "1w 10d 5h 10m 4s",
  "1w 10d 5h    10m 4s",
  "1d 5h 5d",
  "1.2d 5h 5,2d",
  "1w 5d 4.6h 5.2m    7.42s 10,10s 6h5m 10H 5,0H 5x w10h   "
].forEach(s => console.log(`${s}: ${pattern.test(s)}`));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I now understand what I was missing and why every match was validating the string. Also thanks for the tips regarding escaping and usage of pipe.